# require function that uses for await loop

Tags: node.js, readline, for-await

I have a file where I defined a function that uses a for await loop for reading a file:

```
// updater.js
const lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('./my-file.txt'),
})

const updateFile = async () => {
  // stuff..
  for await (const line of lineReader) {
    // do something...
  }
}

module.exports = {
  updateFile,
}
```

The function simply reads a file line by line, looking for a certain pattern that identifies a line that has to be updated; and saves line by line to another file with updates in place;

the thing is that this works correctly if at the end of the file I add `updateFile()` and execute it with `node updater.js`

What I'd like to do, is to require `updater.js` from another script:

```
// main.js
const updater = require('./updater')

const start = async () => {
  console.log('start')
  // do stuff...
  await updater.updateFile()

  console.log('end')
}

start()
```

ok so this is not working since it reaches the first console.log, it enters the `updateFile` method, it executes correctly until the `for await` loop, then the script ends, without throwing any error...
I'm not really understanding this behavior, if someone has some clue I would be grateful...

Comment: Does the console log `end`?

Comment: @Mulhoon no, it just ends

Comment: What is the contents of your `./my-file.txt` file? and do you include `const fs = require('fs')` in `updater.js`?

Comment: yes I do require 'fs' in updater too; my-file.txt is just text

Comment: I tried this locally, and it worked as expected. What node version are you using?